# How can you apply StyleCop settings for all projects using CMake?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake, stylecop

I have many C# projects in my Visual Studio solution, and I want to change to StyleCop settings for all of them. How can I use CMake to ensure that when others pull my code and work with my solution, they can use the same StyleCop rules that I have set up, and have those rules apply to the entire solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure StyleCop settings apply to all of the projects in the solution, you have to place the `Settings.StyleCop` file in the root directory of the solution, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35746167/3987854). Once you've finalized your StyleCop rules in the settings file, you can put the settings file in your source, for example here `input/Settings.StyleCop`. In your top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file, you can tell CMake to copy the settings file into your build directory as a sibling of the generated solution file:

```
configure_file(input/Settings.StyleCop Settings.StyleCop COPYONLY)
```